# Coldfusion - Add records to database via email

Tags: coldfusion

I know this must be possible but can't find anything via a google search. I would like to be able to add a record to my database by sending an email to a monitored inbox. Similar to how most ticketing systems will add case notes to an open case by emailing a particular mailbox and including the case token in the subject.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: I haven't done it, but would imagine the process is exactly what you described. Periodically check an email inbox with something like cfimap. Read the emails and do something with the results, log to a file, insert into db, ...

Comment: How would you go about parsing the subject and body of the email?

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-i/cfimap.html) first. Tags like cfimap and cfpop do that for you.

Comment: i was actually playing about with cfimap on friday for the first time, its pretty easy - dump the results and you can see all the fields - but its kinda slow. you'll have to keep your inbox clean - move or mark the processed emails so next time they don't get retrieved again

Comment: @luke - Yeah, I don't think the cf tags/functions are tuned for large inboxes, so cleaning/moving would be need to be part of any routine.